# Boost protocol_type namespace

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-asio

Working in C++11 makes me feel like an idiot.

I'm writing a simple wrapper class for Boost Socket (`boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`). I'm wrapping one of Socket's functions, **open()**. It takes a `protocol_type`. Looking through the Boost headers, its namespace should be `boost::asio::`. I included boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp just for good measure, since it contains the concrete defintion of ‘protocol_type`.

gcc says "‘protocol_type’ in namespace ‘boost::asio’ does not name a type". I've tried dozens of headers and more namespaces to get it resolved. Here is exactly what I have:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp>

namespace sprocketa{

class BoostSocketWrapper {
public:
    /**
     * @brief Constructor that creates the Boost Socket
     *
     * @param ioService
     */
    BoostSocketWrapper(boost::asio::io_service& ioService);

    // with the exception of "virtual", this is the exact same signature as in the Boost Socket class
    virtual void open( const boost::asio::basic_socket::protocol_type & protocol = boost::asio::protocol_type() );

private:
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> theSocket = nullptr;
};

}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`basic_socket` is a class template which takes 2 parameters, you have to define them:

```
template <typename Protocol, typename SocketService>
class basic_socket
  : public basic_io_object<SocketService>,
    public socket_base
{
public:
  /// The protocol type.
  typedef Protocol protocol_type;
```

`protocol_type` is what you pass as first template parameter, for instance `boost::asio::ip::udp`:

```
// with the exception of "virtual", this is the exact same signature as in the Boost Socket class
virtual void open( const boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp,
    boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp> >::protocol_type & protocol =
    boost::asio::ip::udp::v4() );
```

Comment: Thanks, rafix07. That clears things up a little. But from your example above, I get ‘stream_socket_service’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio’, which is amazing, since I can look right into the stream_socket_service header file and see that it's in the boost::asio namespace (actually, I get a lot of errors; that's just the first one). The only headers I'm including are boost/asio.hpp and boost/asio/stream_socket_service.hpp. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @Frecklefoot Only one header is necessary `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`. Which version of boost do you use ? Can you post compiler error ? I guess other errors are linker errors, you need to add libraries to link your app.

Comment: The exact error I get is **‘stream_socket_service’ is not a member of ‘boost::asio’**

I get a second identical error for the exact same line.

Then I get: **"wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)"** for the same line.

We are linking to the Boost libraries. There are other components in this project that use Boost, and they compile fine.
We're using Boost version **1_66**.

Comment: @Frecklefoot Ups, I have tested local with 1.65.1 version, in 1.66 there are changes, change `open` method declaration to `virtual void open( const boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp>::protocol_type & protocol =
    boost::asio::ip::udp::v4() );` there is no second template parameter. It works, tested on ->  [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e07d1b9bbb2dd557). {coliru has 1.66 boost version}

Comment: Looking at errors endpoint elsewhere, I could determine what it wanted was: **boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::udp>::protocol_type**. I shoved that in the method signature and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey, we arrived at the same solution at the same time! Thanks again!